# What's the most efficient way to check if DB contains a specific primary key value?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'd like to do something like this:

```
public boolean containsKey(int primaryKey) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    // what should i do here to determine if the db contains the primaryKey?
}
```

What is the most efficient way to check if the db contains the specified value?

Comment: It contains a primary key by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to read the row with that PK value:

```java
public boolean containsKey(int primaryKey) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("TableName", null, "IDColumn = " + primaryKey,
                             null, null, null, null);
    return cursor.moveToFirst();
}
```

However, it would be a better idea to use a [helper function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that allows you to avoid having to muck around with a cursor:

```java
public boolean containsKey(int primaryKey) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "TableName", "IDColumn = " + primaryKey) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect sqlite scheme. You may try

`"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"`

Second variant:

`PRAGMA table_info(table-name);`

Answer (score 0):

If You are looking for getting the column names for a table:

```
PRAGMA table_info(your_table_name);
```

Example :

```
PRAGMA table_info(Login);
```

**you will get pk value 1 if you have primary key in login table**.

Check this tutorial on [PRAGMA](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info)

> This pragma returns one row for each column in the named table.
>   Columns in the result set include the column name, data type, whether
>   or not the column can be NULL, and the default value for the column.
>   **The "pk" column in the result set is zero for columns that are not
>   part of the primary key**, and is the index of the column in the primary
>   key for columns that are part of the primary key.

Comment: no, he is not looking for getting the column names for a table, he just wants to check if the table contains `int primaryKey` passed as a parameter

Comment: i know, he want to check if pk is there or not.

Comment: @user8 will get column value 1 if pk exist else 0 from particular table.

Comment: if you know so how could `PRAGMA table_info` help?

Comment: if value is 1 than pk exist else not

Comment: ok, in another words: he wants to check if there is a **row** in his db containing `int primaryKey` passed as a parameter

Comment: yes, @user8 will get result from this query and than he can manipulate it.

Comment: he wants to check if there is a row matching some criteria, he already knows what fields are in his table...